# what would be the simplest way to get the value based on some comparison in pyspark?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I'm playing around with some acceptance criteria and one of the requests is quite simple where I need to return the sum value of a column when the value of another column equals: `xycvg`.

I've written this bit of code and was just wondering: Is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
df.groupBy('Mea_Desc').agg(sum('Meas_Val').alias("Totl")).filter(col('Mea_Desc') == 'xycvg').collect()[0][1]
```

This returns: `Decimal('10366755770.00')`

Comment: sample input, output? Your question is vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

df.filter(df["column2"] == "xycvg").agg(sum("column1")).show()
```

Just replace the name of the columns as you need.